# Combine text of a column in dataframe with conditions in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-cleaning, data-processing

I'm am testing a ML model and need to merge my text to cut my audio file and train the model. How can I merge the text using conditions ?

My goal is to merge the text in the 'Text' column until I reach an end punctuation to form a sentence. I want to continue to form sentences until I reach the end of the text file.

I have tried to use pandas groupby.

```
df.groupby(['Name','Speaker','StTime','EnTime'])['Text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()


Example:

Name  Speaker StTime    Text              EnTime
s1     tom     6.8     I would say  7.3
s1     tom     7.3                      7.6
s1     tom     7.6     leap frog    8.3
s1     tom     8.3                      9.2
s1     tom     9.2       a pig.         10.1




Name  Speaker StTime     Text                            EnTime
s1     tom     6.8     I would say leap frog a pig.       10.1
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name','Speaker'])['Text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()` , remove the other 2 cols from the groupby

Comment: In `Text` column with no values are `NaN`s ? Or empty strings?

Comment: @jezrael The text column with no values are empty strings.

Comment: Ok, is only one sentence per Name and Speaker column? Or possible multiple?

Comment: @jezrael It will always be one sentence per Name and Speaker column.

Comment: @Shana Thankyou, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
>>> df['Text'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'Speaker'])['Text'].transform(' '.join).str.split().str.join(' ')
>>> df2 = df.head(1)
>>> df2['EnTime'] = df['EnTime'].iloc[-1]
>>> df2
  Name Speaker  StTime                          Text  EnTime
0   s1     tom     6.8  I would say leap frog a pig.    10.1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with added functions [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and for column `Text` is use custom lambda function with filter out empty string:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Name','Speaker'], sort=False)
         .agg({'StTime':'first', 
               'Text': lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x if y != ''),
               'EnTime':'last'})
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Name Speaker  StTime                          Text  EnTime
0   s1     tom     6.8  I would say leap frog a pig.    10.1
```